# Twig template (unable to create cache directory)

Tags: php, caching, permissions, twig, template-engine

Installed twig templating system into my application and works fine however when i attempt to specify a cache directory within the configuration it doesn't allow me to continue "Unable to create the cache directory (../view/c/91)".

However when I set the cache to just "cache", for some reason it writes the cache folder into the root of my drive rather than the root of the web folder where it is hosted?

```
$loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem('../view');
$twigConfig = [
    'debug' => true,
    'cache' => '../view/cache'
];

App::register('view', 'Twig_Environment', array($loader, $twigConfig), function($twig) {
    $twig->addExtension(new Twig_Extension_Debug());
});
```

Comment: Added to main post

Comment: Not sure but use full path like `__DIR__ . '/view/cache '`

Comment: Tried this earlier and sadly didn't work, returns "Unable to create the cache directory (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\site\public../view/cache/91"

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem(__DIR__ . '/view');
$twigConfig = [
    'debug' => true,
    'cache' => __DIR__ . '/view/cache'
];

App::register('view', 'Twig_Environment', array($loader, $twigConfig), function($twig) {
    $twig->addExtension(new Twig_Extension_Debug());
});
```

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Twig_Error_Loader' with message 'The "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\site\public../view" directory does not exist.'

Comment: the result link is weird "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\site\public../view"

Comment: Yeah, I thought that too and i'm not sure why

Answer (score 0):

`'cache' => __DIR__ . '/view/cache'`  instead use

```
'cache' => $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'your_folder_structure/view/cache'
```